# Filter child of child of child in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am learning front-end development on my own and I currently implementing a job listing website with a search function. I want to filter based on the title of the position typed.

I have a picture here: [search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFGOv.png)

So What I am trying to filter is 
jobBoard > children > job-title > h2

**HTML:**

```
                        <ul class="job-board">
                            <li class="job job-1">
                                <div class="job-title">
                                    <h2>Process Engineer</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="job-location">
                                    <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="job-type">
                                        <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="job-date">
                                        <p>Published on 07/19/2019</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="job job-2">
                                    <div class="job-title">
                                        <h2>Chief Financial Officier</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="job-location">
                                        <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="job-type">
                                            <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="job-date">
                                            <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="job job-3">
                                        <div class="job-title">
                                            <h2>Assistant CEO</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="job-location">
                                            <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="job-type">
                                                <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="job-date">
                                                <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="job job-4">
                                            <div class="job-title">
                                                <h2>Front-End Developer</h2>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="job-location">
                                                <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="job-type">
                                                    <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="job-date">
                                                    <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>          
                        </ul>
```

**JS:**
This is what I what tried so far. I am not sure how I can do it but it should be something like jobBoard >children > job-title selector > h2

```
    const jobBoard = document.querySelector(".job-board");
const title = document.getElementsByClassName("job-title");
const search = document.querySelector(".skills");


const filterTodos = (term) =>{
    console.log(Array.from(jobBoard.children)
    .filter((post)=>{
        console.log(post.textContent);
        return true;
    }));
};




search.addEventListener("keyup", () =>{
    const term = search.value.trim();
    filterTodos(term);
    console.log(term);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: what result do you need exactly ? filtering the job list by removing all non-matching .job li ?

Comment: Bonsoir François, yes I would like to remove all non-marching job li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you weren't that far from it! I would simply store an array of job-nodes (e.g. child nodes of the job-board) and filter that on `keyup`, then simply call `.querySelector` on the job-element itself during filtering, e.g. `job.querySelector('.job-title')` to get the job title and then go on from there:

```js
const jobs = Array.from(document.querySelector('.job-board').children);
const search = document.querySelector('.skills');


const filterJobs = term => {
  jobs.filter(job => {
    const title = job.querySelector('.job-title').textContent.toLowerCase();
    
    if ( title.includes(term.toLowerCase()) ) {
      job.style.display = 'list-item';
    } else {
      job.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
};

search.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  filterJobs(e.currentTarget.value.trim());
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="skills" placeholder="Filter Jobs" />

<ul class="job-board">
  <li class="job">
    <div class="job-title">
      <h2>Process Engineer</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="job-location">
      <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-type">
      <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-date">
      <p>Published on 07/19/2019</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="job">
    <div class="job-title">
      <h2>Chief Financial Officier</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="job-location">
      <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-type">
      <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-date">
      <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="job">
    <div class="job-title">
      <h2>Assistant CEO</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="job-location">
      <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-type">
      <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-date">
      <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="job">
    <div class="job-title">
      <h2>Front-End Developer</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="job-location">
      <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-type">
      <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-date">
      <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*Note that I made the search/filtering case-insensitive by casting both the job-title and the search-term to lower case, if you want it to be case-sensitive, simply remove the two `toLowerCase()` calls!*

Comment: Damn dude, I was actually looking for something to fix the upper/lower case problem! thank you

Comment: @Gerard1999 also note that both `Array.from()` and `Array.prototype.includes()` are NOT supported by IE, if you need browser support for that you could change that to `Array.prototype.slice.call()` (to replace `Array.from()`) and use `title.indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) !== -1` to replace `includes()`, also arrow functions are not supported by IE!

Comment: Thank you, I do not think I want support for IE. but since it's for Asia, perhaps more people are using IE

Comment: yeah, especially if you're targeting China, that's where IE still has quite some market share unfortunately...

Comment: I was actually wondering of something. I am going to finish the front-end part by this week before to start the back-end (node.js + mongoDB or MySQL). I was actually wondering if the search function should have been implemented by filtering on the database rather than on the front end directly? I hope my question makes sense

Comment: I'd say it depends on the size of your job-listings, if you have 100 jobs, it's not a problem to do it in the frontend directly and fetch it once from the DB, but if you have 100'000 jobs you will need to think about pagination etc because you don't want the user to wait for 100'000 jobs to load... if you do filtering like that to a DB server, you might quickly run into scaling issues...the filter above would send an AJAX request on every keyup, which is way too often (think if 1000 users search at the same time...), so you better go with a traditional search bar with a "seach" button

Answer (score 0):

To get all those listings, it's fairly simple using `querySelectorAll`.

```
const listings = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul.job-board > li.job > div.job-title > h2")];
```

This will give you an array of job titles that you can perform filters on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```js
const titles = document.querySelectorAll("ul.job-board > li.job > div.job-title > h2");

    function search(term){
        for(var j in titles){
            if(titles[j].innerHTML.indexOf(term) > -1){
                titles[j].parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else{
                titles[j].parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="search(this.value);">
<ul class="job-board">
    <li class="job job-1">
        <div class="job-title">
            <h2>Process Engineer</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="job-location">
            <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-type">
                <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-date">
                <p>Published on 07/19/2019</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="job job-2">
        <div class="job-title">
            <h2>Chief Financial Officier</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="job-location">
            <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-type">
                <p>Type: Full-Time</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-date">
                <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="job job-3">
        <div class="job-title">
            <h2>Assistant CEO</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="job-location">
            <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-type">
                <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-date">
                <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="job job-4">
        <div class="job-title">
            <h2>Front-End Developer</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="job-location">
            <p>Location: Naypyitaw</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-type">
                <p>Type: Part-Time</p>
        </div>
        <div class="job-date">
                <p>Published on 07/18/2019</p>
        </div>
    </li>          
</ul>
```

Or you can also do it via `eventListener` like in your example, but the logic stay the same... My example is also case sensitive which is probably something you want to change.

Comment: Thank you so much François. It is working, now I am going to re-do it on my own to understand. Otherwise, do you think the structure of my code is ok? I am also self-self (I started to learn front end 2 months ago), this project is actually for someone and the website is going to be published.

Comment: Your code seems ok, you could just us a loop like in my search function, and put it in your filterTodos function... something like that

Comment: I was actually wondering of something. I am going to finish the front-end part by this week before to start the back-end (node.js + mongoDB or MySQL). I was actually wondering if the search function should have been implemented by filtering on the database rather than on the front end directly? I hope my question makes sense

Comment: It depends... if you plan on loading the complete list of listings to the client's browser by default, there is nothing wrong with a front-end filter function, but it is probably something you want to avoid, especially if you think the total number of listings will be big... The best thing for you is probably to load the x more recent listing by default, and implement either a paging system or even better an infinite scroll. Then, when the user search for a term, send an ajax call to back-end that will search your DB for matching results, etc...

Comment: Thank you François! I am going to implement a paging system (I think we will have maximum 200-300 offers in total). Just last question if you have 2 minutes, is MongoDB enough for that or I should use mySQL? thanks!

Comment: im not familiar with mongodb, but im pretty sure it is enought !

Answer (score 0):

By using jquery I made this for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/f94h2dpL/2/

```
function filter(searchTerm){
$('#jobs li .job-title').each(function(e){
        var jobTitle = $(this).find("h2").text();
    if (jobTitle.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
        } else {
    $(this).parent().show();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will also try it and try to understand

Comment: I was actually wondering of something. I am going to finish the front-end part by this week before to start the back-end (node.js + mongoDB or MySQL). I was actually wondering if the search function should have been implemented by filtering on the database rather than on the front end directly? I hope my question makes sense

Comment: your question does make sense. Both options are good. The front-end can make you filter your data while fetching the data only once. If you are letting the database do the filtering, you will keep fetching new data that is filtered. You could also take a look into https://datatables.net/  . Hope this helps.